# redirect after formview insert command

Tags: asp.net, insert, formview

I'm trying to redirect after a successful insert command on a formview.  Here's what I have:

Detail.aspx:

```
<asp:FormView id="formview1"...datasourceid="detailsSQLDS">
   <InsertItemTemplate>
        DateOfService: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="DateOfServiceTextBox" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("DateOfService") %>' />
        <br />
        InsurancePrimary:
        <asp:TextBox ID="InsurancePrimaryTextBox" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("InsurancePrimary") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />

   </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FOrmView>
....
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="detailsSQLDS" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="..." 
    InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    InsertCommand="usp_Insert"
 >
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void formview1_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect( "List.aspx?mrn=" + Request.QueryString["mrn"] );
}
```

The insert works fine, but not the redirect.  I don't think it's firing the function formview1_ItemInserted(....).  Is there a way to tell the formview to fire this function after a successful insert, or some other way of doing this?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try having a break point in this event while debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I found it.  I needed to add the OnItemInserted="formview1_ItemInserted" declaration to my formview.  So i've got:

```
 <asp:FormView id="formview1"...datasourceid="detailsSQLDS" OnItemInserted="formview1_Item_Inserted">
```

Now it works great.